# Background-image style attribute in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, styles, background-image

I'm trying to apply a background image using a style tag on a div that's reference in JavaScript. I'm sure it's something to do with the quotations around the image variables. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function appendData () {
 var image = "http://domain.com/image.jpg";
 var html = '<div class="itemImage" style="background-image:url(' + image +    ');"></div>';
 $('.container').append(html);
}
```

Comment: you should tag **jQuery** as well, since you are using it in your last line :)

Comment: What is the CSS for itemImage? I am interested to know the height and width of the div. Also try surrounding the url with double quotes: url("' + image + '")

Comment: Guessing: is it a cross-origin problem?

Comment: Have you checked if the image is larger than the div you have put it inside?  It could be rendered but due to size you might only be seeing a small portion of the empty space around it.  [codepen](http://codepen.io/kriddy800/pen/ZOXYRk) shows that it should work as is assuming no cors or background-size issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function appendData () {
 var image = "http://domain.com/image.jpg";
 var html = '<div class="itemImage" style="background-image:url(\'' + image +    '\');"></div>';
 $('.container').append(html);
}
```

Comment: Marco - Perfect. Thank you! - I can accept the answer in 6 minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

I would consider changing your approach slightly.  Sure, you can append the html to your container OR you could change the property of the itemImage without re-writing it every time.

If you build the itemImage div into that container you could do this instead

```
function appendData () {
  var image = "http://domain.com/image.jpg";
  $(".itemImage").css("background-image", image);
}
```

Comment: I never thought of that, that's some good advice. Thanks John :)

Comment: No prob!  I try to avoid inserting HTML whenever possible.